# Java script: not working .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple calculator and my function is not working:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mathLine">0</div>
<div id="score">none</div>
<button id="clear" class = "num" ocnlick="clear(0)">C</button>
<button id="exp" class = "num" >exp</button>
<button id="sqrt" class = "num">sqrt</button>
<button id="buttonide" class = "num">/</button>
<button id="seven7" class = "num" onclick="numerical(7)">7</button>
<button id="eight8" class = "num" onclick="numerical(8)">8</button>
<button id="nine9" class = "num" onclick="numerical(9)">9</button>
<button id="multiply" class = "num" onclick="numerical('X')">X</button>
```

**JS**

```
var equation = [];  
function numerical(number){
    equation.push(number);
    document.getElementById('mathLine').innerHTML = equation;
    console.log(equation);
};
function clear (j) {
    for (j; j < (equation.length+2); j++){
    equation.pop();
    }
    console.log(equation);
    document.getElementById('mathLine').innerHTML = "0";
};
```

Some more info:

- js file is correctly implemented in html;
- the first function (numerical) is working fine;
- List item when I tried it in separate html file, where I put html and js in  tag it all worked

So I have no idea, what's wrong... Maybe I'm looking at it too long and I'm not seeing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as FireBug to get any error messages?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, and you haven't said specifically what isn't working. What *exactly* is the problem you need help with?

Comment: @dlsso It's not as clear as it could be, but Olka says that the first function works, but not the second - and the question title indicates `.innerHTML` is not working as expected. It sounds like the mathLine's text does not change.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal debugger to detect your typos. Use a proper debugger. Even the StackOverflow syntax highlighter tells there is something wrong with that event handler.

Comment: #atjoedonahue  - no, I will try this one. Thanks.

Comment: #Oriol - I'm new starter to js, but also stack and everything in this area:)  So a little bit of patience please. If, in your opinion, this is not the best place to solve easy questions maybe you could advise me some other forum, where such people like me can get help? It would be really great:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Try changing "ocnlick" to "onclick."

Comment: Oh, that's right! It's still not working, but it's one step forward:)

Answer (score 0):

My belief here is that your array-clearing is not working - it's usually not safe to iterate through an array while you are removing elements from it, as the indexing can get messed up. You could perhaps replace the for loop with a while loop checking the array's length, but a simple suggestion would be instead to reassign the array:

```
equation = [];
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you!